# PHP8 ZipArchive EM constant TRAD_PKWARE not working

Tags: php, php-8, php-ziparchive, pkware

i used ZipArchive::EM_TRAD_PKWARE, with password, but zip file is not encrypted. I think that pkware not working. Have solutions ?

Thx

```
$zip->setEncryptionName('test.txt', ZipArchive::EM_TRAD_PKWARE, 'PASSWORD');
```

Answer (score 1):

I got it working by the following example and rules:

## Two rules to make it work

I got inconsistent results when not following these 2 rules:

1. Make sure the file to be encrypted contains data
2. Make sure `addFile` is called before `setEncryptionName`

## Working example

### test.txt

Create the following test.txt file with the following content:

```
test
```

### test.php

Add the following PHP code to test.php:

```php
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$zip->open("test.zip", ZipArchive::CREATE);
$zip->addFile("test.txt");
$zip->setEncryptionName('test.txt', ZipArchive::EM_TRAD_PKWARE, 'PASSWORD'); 
$zip->close();
```

### Run test.php

`php test.php`

A zip file is now created which prompts for a password on unzip.

Comment: Thx for answer. I have this strucutre, and i create your example, but when i open a zip file, password not required. I can open the test.txt

Comment: Strange, which OS are you using and which php version?

Comment: Tested and working. See properties with 7-zip get these result. Method: ZipCrypto Store, Characteristics: Encrypt Descriptor, Packed Size: 17, CRC: 3610A686. Password asked. Tested on Windows 10 PHP 8.0.8

Comment: @Douma Linux Ubuntu, and PHP Version 8.0.11, Zip version 1.19.4, Libzip 1.5.2.

Comment: @vee I have test.txt, packed size: 2, encrypted: -, CRC: 0F149D8B, Method: Store,

Comment: @LukášMesároš This is strange. It must be one of PHP library or external library. I'm using PHP zip 1.19.3, Libzip 1.7.1, BZIP2 compression: yes, XZ compression: yes, AES-128 encryption: yes, AES-192 encryption: yes, AES-256 encryption: yes, otherwise: no

Comment: @vee When i used AES, method in properties file was "AES256". But PKWARE dont work

Comment: I'm running libzip 1.8.0. Maybe you can try to update to a newer version.

Comment: Yes, i must update to a newer version of libzip. Thanks guys